# "Donation" or "donations"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Should I say *send your **donations** and support to* or *send your **donation** and support to*?

I would like to confirm which is right to use when I ask people to donate to a charity. I have read other instances but those have to do with donation policies.

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty with the count of "donations" relates to the number of people the pronoun "your" refers to.  If that is a plural "you", then "donations" is the most correct use.  Also, "donation" reads as though you are asking for a single item or quantity of money, which is probably not true.

I would suggest not using "send" with "support".  It has muddled your intention in the sentence.  I suggest limiting the sentence this way:

> Send your donations to [...].  Your support in any manner is valuable for our cause.

Answer (score 1):

The plural "*donations*", could refer to money - or, other things; such as: canned goods, clothing, bottled water,etc.

"*Send your donation,*" (singular) is usually read as: "Give money." (US)

Comment: I don't think there is anything to indicate that one donation means money, whereas many donations means other stuff.